# Action bar options are not showing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMKnD.png)I am new to android, right now I am referring the sunshine app by udacity.com tutorials. The code is the same, but still it is not showing the option settings and doesn't refresh on the action bar
**How could I resolve my problem?**
MainActivity. java code for main menu

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and ForecastFragment.java for refresh menu

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
}
```

the main menu xml file code

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity" >
      <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
     android:orderInCategory="100" />
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
   android:orderInCategory="100" /></menu>
```

the refresh menu is in forecastfragment.xml file code for refrsh menu is

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100" />
```

the manifest file is

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"    
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"      
             android:label="@string/app_name"       
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >       
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"           
              android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

the style.xml file

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
 <!-- Customize your theme here. -->   
<item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>
<!--style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style-->
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: I am new to andriod, right now i am refering sunshine app by udacity.com tutorials. the code is same but still it not showing th options setting and refresh on action bar

Comment: Please post your full code of activity and menu @Rahul Waghmare

Comment: @Shishram i have added me full code will u pls tell me why not my nenu options are not comming

Comment: added an answer, check and let me know if it works for you! @Rahul Waghmare

Comment: can you post your current screen screenshot how does it look like? @Rahul Waghmare

Comment: and how your UI  should be? that will be useful for better understanding.. so post that screen also to get your working answer!

Comment: @Shishram i have added my ui working image pls check it

Comment: the current actionbar is my activity not application, just added in manifest file no-actionbar line so actionbar is not available there  but in application there is i have added actionbar u can see in manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fragment's `onCreateView` method write

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and add this `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);` to your `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
}
```

you can add this below code in your `activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and this in your `MainActivity.java`

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Your complete `MainActivity` should look like this

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }
}
```

}

and if you want to show your refresh menu then you need to put this code in your fragment `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

and you `activity_main.xml` can be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity"
            tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />


        </LinearLayout>
```

it should work...

Comment: sry but it not working still menubar is same without options

Comment: my activity.main contains Framelayout and if i add tool bar over there the 2 menubar are appearing on screen

Comment: Then try removing this setHasOptionsMenu(true); if you have added this.

Comment: posted full activity its working for me you can get idea from there! @RahulWaghmare

Comment: is i have to make new activity or should i just add toolbar option in my framelayout

Comment: just add toolbar only. added xml also you can check.

Comment: Thanks Shishram now the action bar is showing options thank u so much

Comment: Ok, glad I helped. you can accept answer aswell.@RahulWaghmare

Answer (score 0):

In your menu.xml you have to set app:showAsAction="always" and it will show.

Comment: i try this but it comes as name on actionbar

Comment: did you try giving icon to the menu item like android:icon="your icon" ? also remove xmlnx:tools and context tag from menu. because you are using compact theme and resource-auto will do the trick.

Comment: yes I tried that, after adding icons to item icons are visible

Answer (score 0):

Material design does'nt support ActionBar. So you cannot see ActionBar as well as App icon. If you want ActionBar like functionality then you can use toolbar like the following code does...

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Comment: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
    
</FrameLayout>                        will u tell me how i can add toolbar in my frame layout

Comment: if i add tool bar in my activity.main then 2 action bar are appearing on screen

Answer (score 0):

Extend you baseClass from ActionBarActivity class.

This should take care of this issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
}
```